# Android in Tablelayout in use scrollbar in issue

Tags: android

In android in tablelayout I use ScrollView but my first 2rows data is hide .. when i use scrollview than .
first 2rows are not show when i use to scrollview in this tablelayout . so i want to solution to solve it and i want full data of my code and i want to realy expectation with u to u can solve my problem

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:background="@drawable/titlebar">


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/INFOtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/menu"
        android:text=" IELTS Listening marking schemes"
        />


 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/listening"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="262dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="2dp"
         >


        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip" 
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Score40"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Score/40" 
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BandScore"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BandScore"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score39_40"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:text="39-40"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band9"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score37_38"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="37-38" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band8.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8.5" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score35_36"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="35-36" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band8"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score32_34"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="32-34" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band7.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7.5"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" 
                            android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score30_31"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="30-31" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band7"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score26_29"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="26-29" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band6.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6.5" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
        </TableRow>

         <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score23_25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="23-25" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band6"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

          <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score18_22"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="18-22" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band5.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5.5" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

         <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score16_17"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="16-17" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score13_15"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="13-15" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band4.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4.5" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

     <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score10_12"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10-12" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

      <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score8_10"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8-10" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band3.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3.5" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

       <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score6_7"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6-7" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#E5DA90" android:layout_margin="1dip"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score4_5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4-5" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/band2.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2.5" 
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

  </ScrollView>
         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnback"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:text="Back" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Jaymin, welcome to StackOverflow :) Unfortunately your question is hard to understand (on the language level). It doesn't have to be perfect english, but please try to reformulate your question, so we understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/listening"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="262dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
     >
```

to:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/listening"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
     >
```

By declaring a certain height for the TableLayout, you won't be able to see everything under the TableLayout, therefore you should assign a height that equals to the parent ScrollView's height - wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because the tableLayout is centered in the scrollView. Remove the attribut `android:layout_gravity="center"` from your tableLayout element and it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and its running perfectly.

Please note the scrollview will take effect only on runtime.

If you are checking that in design mode then you will not be able to see all the rows.

Have you ran your app and checked it?